# Dirted hardcore

Tags: meaning

Is this a common slang in US? If this is common, what is the meaning of it? I found only one hit from google search. It's [here.](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=dirted)

Comment: I've never heard it before.

Comment: @snailplane In that case, can you please give a slang word having similar meaning?

Comment: I think it is just one step evolved from "[do someone dirt](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/dirt)", which, according to Macmillan, means "to treat someone very badly".

Comment: Lol. I'm not a native speaker but why I immediately understand (or misunderstand) it as some category on a porn site?!

Comment: "Hardcore" means "the most intense" but it has a close connotation with porn. You would not use "Hardcore" in a formal context. However, it's frequently used in less-formal settings and few will be confused: "This is hardcore coffee" to mean strong coffee, Hardcore punk is a specific type of punk music, etc.

Answer (score 2):

As a native speaker of American English (Midwest and East Coast) I've never encountered the word **dirted** in slang or any other use. An appropriate alternate word would be [**dissed**](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/diss#English), meaning 'disrespected'. In the original context the phrase would change to:

> *...you were **dissed** hardcore.*

In this context, hardcore means 'intensely' or 'severly', as in [definition 2 here](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/hardcore#English). It is worth noting that while the definition shows 'hardcore' as an adjective, it can also be used as an adverb in cases such as the above example.

Hope that helps.